# que debo modificar para sumar cada digito

Tags: python, python-3.x

calculadoraMes("Enero,4,3,4;Febrero,4,3;Marzo,4,3,4;Abril,4,3,4,4" ,"daniel")

y que me imprima

`['Daniel', {'Enero': 11, 'Febrero': 7, 'Marzo': 11, 'Abril': 15}]`

He tratado pero no se como

```
def Calculadorames(registro,nombre):
    dic=dict(((lambda i:(i[0],int(i[1])+int(i[2])))(l.split(',')) for l in registro.split(';')))
    tupla=(nombre,dic)
    return tupla
    
print(Calculadorames("Enero,4,6,4;Febrero,4,3;Marzo,4,3,4;Abril,4,3,4,4","Daniel"))
```

He podido sumar los dos primeros dígitos de cada mes pero debo sumar todos

Answer (score 0):

Es tan fácil como usar la función `sum()` donde le pasaremos el iterable

```py
def Calculadorames(registro,nombre):
    dic=dict(((lambda i:(i[0],sum([int(n) for n in i[1:]])))(l.split(',')) for l in registro.split(';')))
    ...
```

a la funcion `sum()` le pasamos una lista para que sume sus elementos, para eso tendremos que convertir cada elemento a un entero, lo hacemos con `int(n) for n in i[1:]`, la notación `i[1:]` significa que cogerá los elementos de la posición `1` hasta el final, hacemos esto por que sabemos que en la primera posición esta el nombre y luego están los números.

**Salida**

```
('Daniel', {'Enero': 14, 'Febrero': 7, 'Marzo': 11, 'Abril': 15})
```

Comment: vale muchimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Una solución: primero dividir el texto en los ";", lo que nos da los meses:

```
Enero,4,6,4
Febrero,4,3
Marzo,4,3,4
Abril,4,3,4,4
```

Luego dividimos cada mes por los ",", obteniendo una lisat. El primer elemento será el nombre del mes, el resto los valores:

```
['Enero', '4', '6', '4']
```

Para convertir la sublista de enteros, usamos `map` para aplicar la función `int` a cada elemento. Sumamos los valores y agregamos un elemento al diccionario final.

```
texto = "Enero,4,6,4;Febrero,4,3;Marzo,4,3,4;Abril,4,3,4,4"
final = {}
for mes in texto.split(";"):
    val = mes.split(',')
    final[val[0]] = sum(map(int, val[1:]))
print(final)
```

produce:

```
{'Enero': 14, 'Febrero': 7, 'Marzo': 11, 'Abril': 15}
```